# Login form with ajax does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

I have 3 files:
1. Simple form with email and password
2. login_validate.php to validate form input against database
3. login.js to perform ajax task

I tried to validate form with just login_validate.php and everything worked for me. But when i tried to use ajax(login.js), it always tells me wrong email and password even I tried to type in correct email and password in form. Below is my code, please advice what is wrong with it?

Here is my form:

```
<div id="login_result"></div>
<form action="login_validate.php" method="post">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my login_validate.php:

```
<?php
require("configs/dbconnect.php");
if(isset($_POST["dangnhap"])){
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
$sql = 'SELECT name, email, pass, visible FROM user WHERE email = "'.$email.'" AND pass =     "'.$pass.'"';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());
$num_rows= mysql_num_rows($result); // Get the number of rows
if($num_rows > 0){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo 1;
$_SESSION["email"]=$row["email"];
$_SESSION["pass"]=$row["pass"];
$_SESSION["name"]=$row["name"];
}
else{
echo 0;
}
}
?>
```

Here is my login.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#email').focus(); // Focus to the username field on body loads
$('#submit').click(function(){ // Create `click` event function for login
    var email = $('#email'); // Get the username field
    var pass = $('#pass'); // Get the password field
    var login_result = $('#login_result'); // Get the login result div
    login_result.html('loading..'); // Set the pre-loader can be an animation
    if(email.val() == ''){ // Check the username values is empty or not
        email.focus(); // focus to the filed
        login_result.html('<span class="error">Enter the username</span>');
        return false;
    }
    if(pass.val() == ''){ // Check the password values is empty or not
        pass.focus();
        login_result.html('<span class="error">Enter the password</span>');
        return false;
    }
    if(email.val() != '' && pass.val() != ''){ // Check the username and password values is not empty and make the ajax request
        var UrlToPass = 'email='+email.val()+'&pass='+pass.val();
        $.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
        type : 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data : UrlToPass,
        url  : 'login_validate.php',
        success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
            if(responseText == 0){
                login_result.html('<span class="error">Username or Password Incorrect!</span>');
            }
            else if(responseText == 1){
                window.location = 'member/';
            }
            else{
                alert('Problem with sql query');
            }
        }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: post variable should not be sent as `$_GET` variables. try: `{var1:val1, ...}` 
And also what is `dangnhap` ? you are not sending any variable like this. os isset(dangnhap) will fail

Comment: Steps : 

1. You can verify the data being passed by putting some debug statements in the php code and displaying it in the success method of the ajax call.
2. You can use, serialize method to serialize the form data - check this http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
3. Add the hidden input "danghap" to the form.

Hope this will help

Comment: sorry that i forgot to change dangnhap=submit.

Comment: @Riad: Please show me how to change to POST variable in my login.js?

Comment: 1) change the name of the submit button. NEVER have something named submit. 2) give the form an ID and change the click to`$("#formID").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); <rest of your code here without the last return false> });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to test the dangnhap.

in PHP  remove the check:

```
isset($_POST["dangnhap"])  //remove it, no checking for submit required. done in JS file.
```

Change in JS:

```
var UrlToPass = {email:email.val(),pass:pass.val()} ;
```

in HTML:

remove the type( `type="submit"` ) attribute as you are using `<button>`

Comment: I did what you suggest, it worked now. It now redirect me to member page. But somehow my sessions are not set as in my login_validate.php? Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: put the `$_Session` variables before `echo 1`. ( and also session_start() at the very first line of the page.)

Answer (score 0):

in login_validate.php

```
if(isset($_POST["dangnhap"])){
```

but in login.js  dangnhap is  not set.

in $.ajax({    data can be an object, you dont have to make it a string

Comment: data can be string ...then he needs to parse as get variable

Comment: yes. i am speaking about about the easy way of doing things :)

Comment: I changed if(isset($_POST["dangnhap"])) to (isset($_POST["submit"])) but still the problem exists.

Comment: please tell me what line of code in login.js should I change to make my strings parsed as Post Variables?

Comment: after changing to submit. change data : UrlToPass,  TO data : {email: email.val(),pass: pass.val(),submit: true}